# Use `dd` to cut file end part

Tags: dd

There is probably simple trick to do this, but I can't figure from man page.

How do I cut last 1MB from file with undetermined size for example, by using `dd`?

Comment: You want a copy of that file, except for the last 1MB, or do you want the last MB copied to another file?

Comment: I want last 1MB

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, assuming you have `stat` and `bash`, you can get the file size with:

```
stat -c %s your_file
```

If you want to extract the last `$amount` bytes for that file with `dd`, you could:

```
dd if=your_file of=extracted_part \
   bs=1 count=$amount \
   skip=$(( $(stat -c %s your_file) - $amount ))
```

But the saner approach would be to use `tail`:

```
tail -c $(( 1024*1024 )) your_file > target_file
```

Comment: No `-c` option for `head`?

Comment: I think he meant +$(( 1024*1024 )) :       -c, --bytes=K
              output the last K bytes; alternatively,  use  -c  +K  to  output
              bytes starting with the Kth of each file

Comment: While `tail` might look saner, using `dd` (with `bs=1k`) saved my day when I had to cut out last few megabytes of 49 GB log file -- it was done instantly, and `tail` was never able to finish because it had to read an discard too much data.

Answer (score 5):

```
dd --help
Usage: dd [OPERAND]...
  or:  dd OPTION
Copy a file, converting and formatting according to the operands.

  bs=BYTES        read and write BYTES bytes at a time (also see ibs=,obs=)
  cbs=BYTES       convert BYTES bytes at a time
  conv=CONVS      convert the file as per the comma separated symbol list
  count=BLOCKS    copy only BLOCKS input blocks
  ibs=BYTES       read BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)
  if=FILE         read from FILE instead of stdin
  iflag=FLAGS     read as per the comma separated symbol list
  obs=BYTES       write BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)
  of=FILE         write to FILE instead of stdout
  oflag=FLAGS     write as per the comma separated symbol list
  seek=BLOCKS     skip BLOCKS obs-sized blocks at start of output
  skip=BLOCKS     skip BLOCKS ibs-sized blocks at start of input
  status=noxfer   suppress transfer statistics

BLOCKS and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes:
c =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024, xM =M
GB =1000*1000*1000, G =1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.
```

If the file size is exactly 10MB, 1024*10 10240K This will leave the last 1024K. 
You should specify the block size you are working with using the ibs and obs options.

```
1M = 1024K 
1024*9 = 9216
```

```
dd if=/10/MB/file of=/9/MB/file count=9216K ibs=1K obs=1K
dd if=/10/MB/file of=/9/MB/file count=9M ibs=1M obs=1M
```

You can also skip the first 1MB of a file, using the skip option to read to the end of the file skipping the first 1MB.

```
dd if=/10/MB/file of=/9/MB/file skip=1M ibs=1M obs=1M
```

Using the seek option you can write a to a specific place in your output file. 
Say you want to keep the first 1MB and over write the last 8MB.

```
dd if=/10/MB/file of=/9/MB/file skip=1M seek=1M count=8M ibs=1M obs=1M
```

You probably need to get some details about your file size to make sure you get the right amount of data in and out.

```
ls -s --block-size 1K ./my/10MB/file
```

```
man ls

       --block-size=SIZE
              use SIZE-byte blocks.  See SIZE format below

       -s, --size
              print the allocated size of each file, in blocks

       SIZE  may  be (or may be an integer optionally followed by) one of fol‐
       lowing: KB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, and so on for G, T,
       P, E, Z, Y.
```

Answer (score 0):

To truncate a file without copying it using `dd`, you want to set the input file to `/dev/null` and let `dd` truncate the output (target) file at the seek point. For example:

`dd if=/dev/null of=somefile.txt bs=1M seek=10`

will truncate *somefile.txt* at 10MB.

However, because your file is of variable length and you want to remove a fixed amount from the end, look at the `truncate` command. This works much more simply as `truncate <file> --size=X` where `X` can be an absolute or relative amount. If the new size is larger, it will also expand a file (using a hole). See:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=somefile.txt bs=1M count=13
13631488 bytes (14 MB, 13 MiB) copied, 0.0661225 s, 206 MB/s
$ ls -lh somefile.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 13M Sep 28 20:18 somefile.txt
$ truncate -s -3M somefile.txt  # remove the trailing 3MB
$ ls -lh somefile.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 10M Sep 28 20:18 somefile.txt
```

The same using `dd`, but without a relative size:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=somefile.txt bs=1M count=13
13631488 bytes (14 MB, 13 MiB) copied, 0.0669367 s, 204 MB/s
$ ls -lh somefile.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 13M Sep 28 20:21 somefile.txt
$ dd if=/dev/null of=somefile.txt bs=1M seek=10
0 bytes copied, 3.6978e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
$ ls -lh somefile.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 10M Sep 28 20:22 somefile.txt
```