# Resume interrupted copying process

Tags: backup, file-copy, storage

How to resume securely and reliably process of copying file `$A` into backup location `$B` done with `pv "$A" > "$B"` or `cat "$A" > "$B"` ?

(let's assume file `$A` is very big, e.g. LVM2 snapshot file)

Is it achievable with `dd` ?

Preffered: bash or python (preferably python3) solutions.

Example scenario: `pv "$A" > "$B"` interrupted after copying 90%. How to resume it, in order to finish copying process but not repeating whole work again ?

Comment: You might like to utilize: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538/9689 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/use-dd-to-cut-file-end-part

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can use dd to skip the blocks.

```
A="file1"
B="file2"

BLOCKSIZE=512  # default bs for dd

size_b=$(stat -c "%s" "$B")
skip_blocks=$((size_b / BLOCKSIZE))

dd if="$A" of="$B" skip=$skip_blocks seek=$skip_blocks bs=$BLOCKSIZE
```

The important parameters here are `skip` as well as `seek`:

- `skip`: skip BLOCKS **ibs-sized** blocks at start of **input**
- `seek`: skip BLOCKS **obs-sized** blocks at start of **output**

Answer (score 10):

You want `rsync`:

```
rsync -a --append "$A" "$B"
```

Comment: I do not want to use rsync. Let's assume A is 1TB and I've copied already 900GB of data and there are 100G remaining. rsync would read whole 1TB, while I need only the last 100G ! -> Read first about algorithm which is used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki  I think you're wrong.  Unless my experience with rsync is entirely wrong, rsync will *read* what it needs to read to verify the output is right, until it hits a point where there start to appear disparities, and then it will continue from that marked point.  This looks to be pretty-much exactly what is needed.

Comment: For this to work you also need to add `--append`.

Comment: Thanks @Thor for stressing this option. As I've double checked it seems that behaviour of `--append` has changed since version 3.0.0. Could you ensure me if currently `--append` ignores already copied part, while `--append-verify` reads whole A for checksum check ? (before version 3.0.0. `--append` behaved like `--append-verify` -> That's the reason of misunderstanding)

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: I hadn't noticed this change. I just tested it, and indeed `--append` blindly appends to the file. `--append-verify` does the same but runs checksums at the end, if the checksums do not match `rsync` seems to do a new copy.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `dd skip` with an offset of B's real file size (independent of the partition block size)?

That would get you the missing part. At that point you could directly `cat` them together into a new file with `cat "$B" "$A2" >> "$C"; #mv "$C" "$B"` (where `$C` is of course the missing part on a path with enough space).

`cat` works fine for concatenating binaries too and in this case you do not have multiple file headers that would precent simple scripted merges. There's a chance the end of `$B` is corrupted, but in that case you could cut it short and reread more of `$A` in the initial dd step.