# Is rsync --append able to resume an interrupted copy process without reading all the copied data?

Tags: rsync, file-copy, large-files

I need to copy one very large file (3TB) on the same machine from one external drive to another. This might take (because of low bandwidth) many days.

So I want to be prepared when I have to interrupt the copying and resume it after, say, a restart.
From [what I've read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44189/resume-interrupted-copying-process/44190#44190) I can use

```
rsync --append
```

for this (with rsync version>3). Two questions about the `--append` flag here:

1. Do I use `rsync --append` for *all* invocations? (For the first invocation when *no* interrupted copy on the destination drive yet exists and for the subsequent invocations when there *is* an interrupted copy at the destination.)
2. Does `rsync --append` resume for the subsequent invocations the copying process *without* reading all the already copied data? (In other words: Does rsync mimic [a `dd`-style seek-and-read operation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44189/resume-interrupted-copying-process/44205#44205)?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do I use `rsync --append` for all invocations?

Yes, you would use it each time (the first time there is nothing to append, so it's a no-op; the second and subsequent times it's actioned). But **do not use `--append` at all** unless you can **guarantee** that the **source is unchanged** from the previous run (if any), because it turns off the checking of what has previously been copied.

> Does `rsync --append` resume for the subsequent invocations… without reading all the already copied data?

Yes, but without `rsync --partial` would probably have first deleted the target file.

The correct invocation would be something like this:

```
rsync -a -vi --append --inplace --partial --progress /path/to/source/  /path/to/target
```

You could remove `--progress` if you didn't want to see a progress indicator, and `-vi` if you are less bothered about a more informational result (you'll still get told if it succeeds or fails). You may see `-P` used in other situations: this is the same as `--partial --progress` and can be used for that here too.

- `--append` to continue after a restart without checking previously transferred data
- `--partial` to keep partially transferred files
- `--inplace` to force the update to be in-place

If you are in any doubt at all that the source might have changed since the first attempt at `rsync`, use the (much) slower `--append-verify` instead of `--append`. Or better still, remove the `--append` flag entirely and let `rsync` delete the target and start copying it again.

Comment: "because it turns off the checking of what has previously been copied" -- Rather than turning off, isn't it because it checks by way of filesize? I would have expected that changes to either destination or source wouldn't cause corruption with `--append` if you use it with `-c`/`--checksum`. EDIT: Indeed it turns it off instead of checksumming to the minimum between the 2 sizes. That's a shame.

Comment: Apparently for `--append` to behave like `--append-verify` when used with `-c`. I hadn't noticed there was that separate option. EDIT: Yes.

Comment: Cool answer! Clears up all my questions in great detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll want to use the `--partial` option. From the manpage:

```
--partial                keep partially transferred files
```

Comment: also `--inplace` option might be needed.  

 --inplace
              This  option  changes  how  rsync transfers a file when its data
              needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a
              new  copy  of  the file and moving it into place when it is com‐
              plete, rsync instead writes the updated  data  directly  to  the
              destination file.

Comment: Tahnks for chiming in! - So I would need `--partial --inplace` for both, first and subsequent invocations?

Comment: I'd also care about the advice given 10 years ago. Which version of rsync in these times ? They possibly meant what more recent rsync would name *append-verify*. Anyway, I always use *append-verify*